# Inner approximation of measure by compact sets.

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose $E$ is Lebesgue measurable set in $\mathbb{R}$. Let $0<a<m(E)$, show that there is a compact set $K$ contained in $E$ such that $m(K)=a$.

I know that $m(E)=\sup \{m(K):K\subset E$, $K$ is compact $\}$.
How do we find such $K$, I tried to prove that $g(x)=m(E\cap [-x,x])$ is continuous, but i can't say that $E\cap[-x,x]$ is compact in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: If $E$ is compact, then $E \cap [-x, x]$ is also compact. A closed subset of a compact space is guaranteed to be compact.

Comment: @Kenny Wong you are correct,  but E is only measurable, we are not given that E is compact.

Comment: Oh right - I misunderstood. My idea was: you know that there exists a compact $K$ such that $m(K) = a + \epsilon$ for small $\epsilon$. Then you can use the fact that $g(x) = m(K \cap [-x, x])$ is continuous.

Comment: Yes, that was the first thought that came to my mind  when I read your comment.thank you!

Comment: @WLET I don't understand your question. You wrote “I know that $m(E)=\sup \{m(K):K\subset E$, $K$ is compact $\}$”. But isn't this what you want to prove?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos what I want to show is that for each positive $a$ less than $m(E)$, we can find a compact K contained in E whose measure is equal to $a$. that equation will only give me that for each $\epsilon$we can find a compact K contained in E such that $m(E-K)$ is less than $\epsilon$

Answer (score 1):

A couple of hints. Since $E\cap [-n,n]$ is an increasing sequence, you have that
$$m(E)=\lim_{n\to\infty}m(E\cap [-n,n])$$ 
and so for $n$ large $m(E\cap [-n,n])>a$. Next prove that the function
$g(x)=m(E\cap [-n,x])$ is Lipschitz continuous, with Lipschitz constant at most one.